# application was not shown in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

this is the problem i'm geting guys...my application was not shown in emulator...
wat to do guys

```
Android Launch!
[2013-08-30 11:00:27 - Resturent1] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-30 11:00:27 - Resturent1] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-08-30 11:00:27 - Resturent1] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-08-30 11:00:27 - Resturent1] Performing sync
[2013-08-30 11:00:28 - Resturent1] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'kamal'
[2013-08-30 11:00:28 - Resturent1] Uploading Resturent1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-08-30 11:00:32 - Resturent1] Installing Resturent1.apk...
[2013-08-30 11:00:40 - Resturent1] Success!
[2013-08-30 11:00:40 - Resturent1] \Resturent1\bin\Resturent1.apk installed on device
```

Comment: restart adb and if required eclipse.

Comment: Just wait - the emulator is [sloooow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: finaly i created a new application and pasted same code into that then its wrkng...bt i want to know the exact reason. what was an error actually

Comment: No Launcher activity found! Have you declared Activity with action:Main and category:Launcher

Comment: @Nargis, please post that as an answer, that is __the__ problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Launcher activity found! Have you declared Activity with action:Main and category:Launcher in your Android Manifest File.